# Remove blank space behind number in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-update

I have a column with a 7 digit number. When the data was imported there were 3 blank spaces imported behind each number. I have tried several different versions of Trim() in an update/select query with no luck. I am using Access 2007.

Below are the different things I have tried:

Select Query

```
Expr1: Trim([Number])
Expr1: RTrim([Number])
```

and Update Query

```
UPDATE Table SET [Number] = Replace([Number], " ", "");
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/remove-spaces-from-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-text-value-HP001099033.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't see why those efforts failed, I'll suggest you try this `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Number] = RTrim([Number])
```

If that does not remove the trailing spaces, what does happen when you try it?  Is there an error message?  Do you perhaps have `SetWarnings` turned off, which can suppress error messages?

Also check whether those field values include characters which aren't visible and could interfere with trimming the spaces.  For example, you can check the ASCII value of the last character in each field like this:

```
SELECT Asc(Right([Number], 1)) AS ascii_value
FROM [Table];
```

A space character is ASCII 32.

Finally, if those suggestions don't lead you to a solution, check to confirm the field contains what you expect.

```
SELECT [Number]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Number] ALike '%   ';
```

Comment: interesting the result of the ASCII select query was 160. Which appears to be a &nbsp; (http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) any ideas on how to remove it? -- Thanks!

Comment: `UPDATE [Table] SET [Number] = Replace([Number], Chr(160), '')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Regular Expression. This will filter out ALL non-numbers.
You would have to create a function in VBA that is called from your query. So, try this:

```
Function NumOnly(S As String) As String
   Dim regex As New RegExp
   regex.Pattern = "[^0-9.-]"
   regex.IgnoreCase = True
   regex.Global = True
   NumOnly = regex.Replace(S, "")
End Function
```

and use it thus:

```
UPDATE Table SET [Number] = NumOnly([Number]);
```

Comment: Yeah, bad assumption on my part. Now edited. However, it still does not validate that the number is properly formatted to begin with (i.e. 1.2.3-4)